# Facing difficulties in suspending a thread with user input in console

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I can suspend the thread with user input in console,but can't resume it again with user input.

I want to resume the thread when user gives input "n". Again it will start with prev state
please help folks.
Thanks.

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;

 class NewThread  implements Runnable {

       String name; // name of thread
       Thread t;
       boolean suspendFlag;
       NewThread(String threadname) {
          name = threadname;
          t = new Thread(this, name);
          System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
          suspendFlag = false;
          t.start(); // Start the thread
       }
       // This is the entry point for thread.
       public void run() {

         //  String username = scanner.nextLine();

          try {
          for(int i = 5000; i > 0; i--) {
             System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
             Thread.sleep(200);

                //String username = scanner.nextLine();
//              if(username.equals("y"))
//              {
//                  mysuspend(); 
//              }

             synchronized(this) {
                while(suspendFlag) {

                   wait();

                }
              }
            }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
          }
          System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
       }
       void mysuspend() {
          suspendFlag = true;
       }
       synchronized void myresume() {
          suspendFlag = false;
           notify();
       }
    }

    class SuspendResume {
       public static void main(String args[]) {


            NewThread ob2 = new NewThread("One");
            // System.out.println(username);
          try { Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          String username = scanner.nextLine();
          if(username.equals("y"))
                {
                    Thread.interrupted();

            // Thread.sleep(10000);
             ob2.mysuspend();
             System.out.println("Suspending thread One");
             Thread.sleep(10000);

            // ob2.myresume();
             System.out.println("Resuming thread One");
                }
          if(username.equals("n"))
            {

              ob2.myresume();
            }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
          }
          // wait for threads to finish
          try {
             System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish.");
             ob2.t.join();

          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
          }
          System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
       }

}
```

Comment: Make sure to set suspendFlag to volatile since you are modifying it between threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your control flow is wrong.

You are reading input only once. If it is equal to `y` you are suspending the thread, but then you never go into the if statement that tests for `n` to resume the thread. I would do it like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        NewThread ob2 = new NewThread("One");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            String username = scanner.nextLine();
            if (username.equals("y")) {
                Thread.interrupted();

                // Thread.sleep(10000);
                ob2.mysuspend();
                System.out.println("Suspending thread One");                    

            }
            if (username.equals("n")) {
                ob2.myresume();
                System.out.println("Resuming thread One");
            }
            if (username.equals("q")) {
                ob2.myresume();
                break;          
            }
        }
        // wait for threads to finish
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish.");
            ob2.t.join();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
    }
}
```

If the user enters "y" the thread will be suspended. If they enter "n" it will be resumed and if they enter "q" you will just break the loop and wait for the thread to finish.

Comment: @ Tudor
it also can resume the thread when user put another speacific input..
i want when user gives "n" the thread will resume again

Comment: @aritra: No, it will not resume it unless you enter "n". Otherwise it will keep looping for another input. Test the code if you want.

Comment: Just as an FYI, remove `Thread.interrupted()`, since you're not checking the result.

Answer (score -1):

1.. You are using methods **wait()** and **notify()** but you want to suspend and resume the thread. So it is **not the right way**. These methods are used to release any resource (synchronized) from one thread to make it available to some other thread and again give that resource back to same thread.

You should use ***only* suspend() and resume()** methods instead.

You cannot use **wait() and notify()** in your program.

2.. Try doing this in the following manner :

Create two threads. One which will get inputs from user and second which you want to suspend and resume.

According to the input of user call suspend and resume methods on second thread.

*In your code you are getting input from user only once. So once thread suspended is never resumed.

Comment: suspend and resume are deprecated. wait and notify are the correct way to do it.

Comment: @aritra, check if what I posted is what you need.